# 404 error not found when debug = False in django multilanguages web app

Tags: python, django, gettext

*Hello I am making a multilanguages django web app,*

When **DEBUG = True =>** the multilanguages works fine means when i click on *localhost:8000* it redirect me to *localhost:8000/en* or the last language I am puting anyway.

When **DEBUG = FALSE =>** I enter to *localhost:8000* it gives me an error of **404 not found**,

here is **my setting.py**:

I am puting the '*' because I am testing if possible to work anyway I am testing all.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost','localhost:8000','127.0.0.1','127.0.0.1:8000','*']
LOCALE_PATHS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'), )
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
LANGUAGES = [
  ('en', ('English')),
  ('ko', ('Korean')),
]
```

here is my **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns (
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app1.urls')),
    path('', include('app2.urls')),
)
handler404='app1.views.handle_not_found'
```

in my **app1 urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('',views.index,name="index"),
]
```

in debug = False it doesn't work so it doesn't know the path of locahost:8000 only it knows only localhost:8000/en how can I do so whenever.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help you but I had configured my translations this way on one of my Django projects:

```
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

# This is defined here as a do-nothing function because we can't import
# django.utils.translation -- that module depends on the settings.
def gettext_noop(s):
    return s

LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),)
LANGUAGES = (
    ('fr', gettext_noop('French')),
    ('en', gettext_noop('English')),
    # ('es', gettext_noop('Spanish')),
    # ('it', gettext_noop('Italian')),
    # ('ar', gettext_noop('Arab')),
)
```

In my `urls.py`:

```
from django.views.i18n import JavaScriptCatalog


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('jsi18n/', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),
]
```

This code is a bit dated but I hope it helps.

Comment: my code is working nice but the problem is only with the debug True and False, when I do it is debug = False and enter to **localhost:8000** it doesn't add the **/en** it gives me 404 error but when I add it myself it show the website normaly... but when debug =  True it add it directly working fine with debug True... my question was how can I make it add **/en** while using **debug =False**